# Unable to successfully build a Jmeter test on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am attempting to run a Jmeter test on jenkins with the following script under windows batch command:

C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin>jmeter -jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t "C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\VibraniumValley.jmx" -l "C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\Reports\VVjenkinsreport.csv"

Jenkin's console output returns the following:
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JmeterJenkinsJob
[JmeterJenkinsJob] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins930034514613825368.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JmeterJenkinsJob>C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin -jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t "C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\VibraniumValley.jmx" -l "C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\Reports\VVjenkinsreport.csv" 1>jmeter
**'C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JmeterJenkinsJob>exit 9009
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Creating parser with percentiles:'0,50,90,100,' filterRegex:
Performance: Recording JMeterCsv reports 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JmeterJenkinsJob\builds\18\temp\VVjenkinsreport.csv'
Performance: JMeterCsv copying reports to master, files '[C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JmeterJenkinsJob\builds\18\temp\VVjenkinsreport.csv]'
Performance: JMeterCsv parsing local reports '[C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JmeterJenkinsJob\builds\18\performance-reports\JMeterCSV\VVjenkinsreport.csv]'
Performance: Parsing report file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JmeterJenkinsJob\builds\18\performance-reports\JMeterCSV\VVjenkinsreport.csv' with filterRegex ''.
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test unstable
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test failure
Performance: **File VVjenkinsreport.csv reported 25.0% of errors [SUCCESS].** **Build status is: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a typo in your command or it's a copy-paste issue. You need to change  `>` to `\`

```
C:\Users\udeme.bassey\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin>jmeter 
                                                                           ^ here
```

Also JMeter [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) are case-sensitive, if you want to pass `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv` parameter to override [.jtl file output format property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) you need to use capital `J` like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

More information: [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, the issue was with the > tag as you pointed out. Its resolved now